Action of homogenous Lorentz transformation on simultaneous energy-momentum eigenstate
This is somewhat a follow up to this question and answer. Consider the restricted Poincaré group
$$\text{RISO}(1,3) := SO^+(1,3) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^4$$
with semidirect product for all $\Lambda, \Lambda' \in SO^+(1,3)$ and $a, a' \in \mathbb{R}^4$
$$(\Lambda', a') \cdot (\Lambda, a) = (\Lambda'\Lambda, a' + \Lambda a).$$
The Poincaré algebra is
$$\mathfrak{iso}(1,3) \cong \mathfrak{so}(1,3) \oplus \mathfrak{t}$$
with induced Lie bracket for all $X, X' \in \mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ and $a, a' \in \mathfrak{t}$
$$[(X', a'), (X, a)] := ([X, X'], X'a - Xa').$$
By definition of the induced Lie bracket,
$$\text{ad}_{(X,0)}(0,a)=(0, Xa),$$
which directly implies at the group level
$$\text{Ad}_{(\Lambda, 0)} (0,a) = (0,\Lambda a).$$
Projecting onto the second factor, this is the statement for all $a \in \mathfrak{t}$
$$\Lambda a\Lambda^{-1} = \Lambda a.$$
Let $\pi$ be an arbitrary unitary projective representation of $\text{RISO}(1,3)$ and $\pi_*$ the induced Lie algebra representation. Let $P \in \mathfrak{t}$ be a generator of translation and $\Phi_{p}$ and eigenstate of $\pi_*(P)$ in the representation space. Then,
$$\begin{aligned} \pi_*(P) \pi(\Lambda)\Phi_{p} &= \pi(\Lambda) \text{Ad}_{\pi(\Lambda)^{-1}} \pi_*(P) \Phi_p \\ &\approx \pi(\Lambda)\pi_*(\text{Ad}_{\Lambda^{-1}}P)\Phi_p \\ &= \pi(\Lambda)\pi_*(\Lambda^{-1}P)\Phi_p, \end{aligned}$$
which is not the expected result
$$\pi(\Lambda)\pi_*(\Lambda P)\Phi_p.$$
I used the "$\approx$" symbol as I am uncertain if this step is correct. I am wondering how to show the expected result in this formalism without using any spacetime indicies.
